# AngularJS - binding array value to input ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have $scope.myArray, and it's binding with an input field by ngModel and the expression {{myArray}}

My issue is when I modified myArray by call changeMyArray(), the input's value did not change. But the expression {{myArray}} is display new value.

So, Why the expression work but input field does not?

I have a way to do, but I want to find a better approach

```
var newArr = $scope.myArray;
newArr.push("b");
$scope.myArray = angular.copy(newArr);;
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/us11jmb9/6/)

Comment: i dont see any input in your fiddle and it is pushing successfully?

Comment: Your example fiddle doesn't have an input. Can you update the example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Can you also add the HTML code of how you are binding the `myArray` variable to the input field? If what you want is to use an input text field to push values into your array, then binding it to the whole array wont work.

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated my link

Comment: You use a different variable name : countChange_watch and countChange when watching the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, I think what you want to do is bind the input to a "new entry" scope variable, and then push the value of that variable to your array when the user clicks "Push To". Here's what I mean:

#### In controller:

```
$scope.changeMyArray = function() {
    $scope.myArray.push($scope.newEntry);
    $scope.newEntry = "";
}
```

#### In HTML:

```
<input ng-model="newEntry">
```

#### But actually:

Really what you want is a way to edit the contents of an array via text, and have updates to that array from elsewhere also update the text. This is actually pretty simple since browsers come with a JSON library.

I implemented it by starting with a known pair of objects:

```
$scope.myArray = [];
$scope.myArrayString = "[]";
```

That way you can update the string via ngModel:

```
<input ng-model="myArrayString">
```

Watch for changes on this model to update the actual array:

```
$scope.$watch("myArrayString", function() {
    $scope.myArray = JSON.parse($scope.myArrayString);
});
```

Then update the string in the `changeMyArray` function:

```
$scope.changeMyArray = function() {
    $scope.myArray.push("b"); // Or whatever you would like to add here
    $scope.myArrayString = JSON.stringify($scope.myArray);
}
```

Experiment [in my fork of the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/us11jmb9/5/).

#### What's going on?

The variable `$scope.myArray` is an object, and any object in Javascript can be converted to a string (most complex objects end up as the unhelpful `"[object Object]"`). Arrays will actually display their contents when converted to a string, so binding an array to HTML via `{{myArray}}` is pretty straightforward.

However, the reverse conversion is not as simple. In general, a text input can't be bound to an array in a two-way fashion as we'd like. The solution, then, is to use an intermediary variable to hold the string value, and use `$scope.$watch` to keep the two values in sync.

Comment: Thank @austin-mullins , but I want to bind the input with myArray. I expect when I push new item in myArray, that change should be updated on input field.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did not understand that from the question. Can you edit the question to provide more information about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank @austin-mullins, I edited my question. Hope it help you understand.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it. Was I closer with my first suggestion or my second?

Comment: Thank Austin, the second is right. Could you explain more for me why when $scope.myArray is modified. Only the expression {{myArray}} display new value, but the input does not ?

Comment: Thank you so much, can I ask you one more, when i update myArray by copy it then re-assign like (http://jsfiddle.net/us11jmb9/9/) . The new value is displayed on input field. Why does this happen?

Comment: Like I said, it's just converting an array to a string, which shows the contents. It's equivalent to `input.value = "" + myArray`.

Comment: Hi @austin , Could you help me to correct my answer which I just posted? Thank you

Comment: I always feel weird editing other people's answers. I appreciate that you actually would like an editor, but you understand why I might feel conflicted. You accepted my answer, but now if you feel yours is better, I'm probably going to lose those 15 points. I can afford it, I just don't know what you want.

Comment: Hi @austin, I'm very sorry if I do something or say something make you feel bad. My EL is not good and I don't often use SOF. I'm learning AngularJS, I confuse what I learn about $watch with what I see in real. That why I post the question above. I don't say my answer is better than you. I post it b/c I think I can share my solution, and if it's wrong, I very happy if someone correct me. I will research and learn more. Thank for your help. I'm very happy if I can share my knowledge with you and everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry, too. I don't feel bad. It's fine to answer your own question. It's actually great that you found different ways to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to be wondering why when pushing to the array, your $watch function doesn't do the increment. That's because the #watch function only checks object reference equality.

When pushing to the array, the reference stays the same. When you copy the array and set it again in the same variable, the reference changes.

That's why @watchCollection works as expected and increments when each item is pushed.

Comment: Thank @sirrocco , Do we have other way to do instead copy the array to change reference?

Comment: Well .. you need to better explain what you want to do. It's really unclear as you can see from other answers/ comments

Comment: Hi @sirrocco , could you help me to correct my answer above?

Answer (score 0):

I have an explanation for my question. Please correct me if I wrong, very thank.

**My Question:**
Why "myArray" input field does not update when $scope.myArray is changed (Model doesn't update View)?

```
<input ng-model="myArray" id="myArray">
```

The answer is AngularJs ng-model doesn't know $scope.myArray is changed. Because ng-model does not perform a deep watch of object (rather than a string or number), it only looks for a change of identity or compares the reference of the objects.

In my case, $scope.myArray is collection. So, although $scope.myArray has changed by push new item (structure is changed), it's reference does not change.

As the result, $setViewValue() and $render() never invoked to update the view.

[$render](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#properties_$render())
[$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#properties_$setViewValue())

**Solution:**

**Sol1:** Add new item to $scope.myArray, make a copy of myArray object and then asign a copy to $scope.myArray again. By this way, the object reference is changed. AngularJs see that change and update the view.

```
var newArr = $scope.myArray;
newArr.push("b");
$scope.myArray = angular.copy(newArr);
```

**Sol2:** Create custome $watch('email', function(){...}, **true**). The last parameter is TRUE to let Angular perform a deep watch. Then, in watch's listener function, I manually set $viewValue = newValue and invoke $render() of ngModelController to update the view. In case we have Formatters, we should invokes them in this step.

```
    $scope.$watch('myArray', function(newValue, oldValue) {
if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        var ctrl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myArray')).controller('ngModel');

        // Invoke formatter
        var formatters = ctrl.$formatters,
          idx = formatters.length;

        while(idx--) {
            newValue = formatters[idx](newValue);
        }

        ctrl.$render();
  }
    }, true);
```

[Please see my script](http://plnkr.co/edit/P93YlO15KyEOtfvQSgTq)